# Stair Project - Closed Stair stringer replacement ideas

Tags: stairs

I have removed the carpet from the stairs and already have the plans on updating the treads with :

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Stairtek-RetroTread-11-5-in-x-36-in-Unfinished-Red-Oak-Stair-Tread/3316912

And doing risers with:

https://www.lowes.com/pd/7-5-in-x-48-in-Unfinished-Unfinished-Pine-Stair-Riser/1000445295

So I will not be removing the old treads/wood (only cutting off the old bullnose before installing the new tread) so looking for suggested directions on how to replace the stringer that is 1" X 12" by approx 15'.   The old looks to be MDF and I want to replace that with stained/painted wood.  Any suggestions on how best to remove the old and add new while the existing treads/risers are still in place?

[image: Water Soaked MDF stringer]

Comment: That's going to be rough without removing the treads/risers. Just my opinion, but are you sure you want to save those and put down $33 tread covers with pine riser "skins"?  The wood grains will not match unless you paint them. You could replace the treads with pine for $12 each and match the risers.

Comment: Of course, if you simply replace the treads and risers, they'll all have to come out. While they're out, it will be easy to replace the trim along the side.

Comment: I see your points.   I have to see if the new treads in that link can replace the existing ones (if they are strong enough).  If so, then I can see your point.  But I'd have to prep/stain them all in advance so that I can do this all in one day if I am going to have to take out the trim